# Stochastic resonance

Tags: mathematical-physics

Having a look at the book Dynamical Cognitive Science, by Lawrence M. Ward, MIT PRESS, I encounter something which might be useful for my research, namely what he calls stochastic resonance, of great importance in bistable physical systems. I would like to get a basic algebraic definition of it, if you were so kind to help me.

Comment: Is something as simple as "up to a certain maximum noise intensity, the signal-to-noise ratio increases as noise intensity increases" sufficient? Or do you want something which describes what "signal" means?

Comment: Well, what I need is the particular way in which it relates to the  double potential well.

Comment: What are the "signal" and "noise" in your double potential well problem?

Comment: Well, I guess the signal would be made up of linguistic (syntactic) constituents, with say, two independent constituents, each of which is bound to the bottom of one well......as for noise.....I do not know, probably something formulated in terms of feature attraction, so that one unit moves to the position of the other so that the features can be checked.